# Error when I try to open http://localhost:3000/pages/home

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home

---

Showing c:/Users/Administrator/desktop/pinteresting/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)

---

Extracted source (around line #6):

---

Pinteresting
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    **<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>**
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Answer (score 1):

It seems like nodejs is not installed on your machine. Install it using

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

or add `execjs` gem in you gemfile.

As for running javaScript code from Ruby we need one of above.